# How to create different objects depending on the parameter passed?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a use-case like this:

Based on the parameter passed - I have to create an object corresponding to it but the underlying functionality remains same.

```
public void selectType ()
{
  String type = "ABC";
  publishType(type);
}

public void publishType(String type)
{
if (type.equals("ABC"))
ABCtype publishObject = new ABCtype();

if (type.equals("XYZ"))
XYZtype publishObject = new XYZtype();

publishObject.setfunctionality();
}
```

What is a better way to approach this? 
Which design pattern does it fall in?

Another doubt I have is - how to initialize publishObject?
It gives an error like this.

Comment: [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) would be a good fit.

Comment: FYI: this is completely wrong: ***if (type =="ABC")*** you are comparing references and not content....

Comment: @Kayaman, this is related to design

Comment: A question that does String comparison wrong cannot be about design.

Comment: that's his mistake, but he is expecting Factory Design

Comment: That string comparison - was a terrible blunder.

Answer (score 1):

> *but the underlying functionality remains same*

you maybe consider design suing interfaces..

Do some nice Archi- Design like:

define an interface, and 2 classes that implement the interface, then
declare an object foo and initialize it according to the parameter..

## Example:

```
interface IObject{
    //methods here
}
class A implements IObject{}
class B implements IObject{}

public void selectType ()
{
    IObject foo = getObject(1);
}

public IObject getObject(int type){
    if (type ==1){
        return new A();
    }else{
        return new B();
    }
}
```